# Writing a method that takes parameters on different lines in Ruby

Tags: ruby

While working with Rails I saw that one could call methods like so.

```
lot = Lot.new do |u|
    u.grade_id = grade.id
    u.company_id = company.id
    u.type_id = type.id
    u.sale_id = sale.id
    u.quantity = lot[6]
    u.price = lot[3]
    u.info = lot[4]
    u.remark = lot[5]
end
```

As you can see, I'm passing the parameters on different lines.

I need to write some methods that take a lot of arguments, and thought that it would be much better if I could invoke my method like this. Could someone show me how to do write methods which accept arguments in a similar fashion? A link to some guide/documentation would be great help. Is this what they call code blocks in Ruby?

Comment: Unsure of what you are asking. A *this is what I have, this is what I need* code snippet will help.

Comment: Hi Zabba. I found a `new` method in RoR and as you cans see from the snippet, I'm passing the params on separate lines. Normally one would invoke a method by so `methodname(param1, param2, param3, etc)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example above doesn't pass any argument. You are simply calling a method and using a block to yield on the new created instance.

This code

```
lot = Lot.new do |u|
    u.grade_id = grade.id
    u.company_id = company.id
end
```

can be written as

```
lot = Lot.new
lot.grade_id = grade.id
lot.company_id = company.id
```

The second example doesn't use a block.

If you want your object to accept blocks on initialization, add the following line of code in your `initialize` file.

```
yield self if block_given?
```

Here's an example

```
class MyObject
  def initialize
    # ...
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer; you might make it clear that the only reason that the first code can be written as the latter is due to the implementation of `Lot`, but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass a block in your method.

```
def initialize(&block)
  yield self
end
```

Comment: Note that catching the block as an argument here is not needed and also a (very slight) performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Diving in deeper, I think you would benefit from a deeper understanding of "Blocks" in Ruby (which are different from the general programming terms "code block" or "block of code").

Pretend for a moment that the following (invalid) Ruby code actually worked:

```
def add10( n )
  puts "#{n} + 10 = #{n+10}"
end

def do_something_with_digits( method )
  1.upto(9) do |i|
    method(i)
  end
end

do_something_with_digits( add10 )
#=> "1 + 10 = 11"
#=> "2 + 10 = 12"
...
#=> "9 + 10 = 19"
```

While that code is invalid, its intent—passing some code to a method and having that method run the code—is possible in Ruby in a variety of ways. One of those ways is "Blocks".

A Block in Ruby is very, very much like a method: it can take some arguments and run code for those. Whenever you see `foo{ |x,y,z| ... }` or `foo do |x,y,z| ... end`, those are blocks that take three parameters and run the `...` on them. *(You might even see that the `upto` method above is being passed a block.)*

Because Blocks are a special part of the Ruby syntax, every method is allowed to be passed a block. Whether or not the method *uses* the block is up to the method. For example:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
end

say_hi("Mom") do
  puts "YOU SUCK!"
end
#=> Hi, Mom!
```

The method above is passed a block that is ready to issue an insult, but since the method never calls the block, only the nice message is printed. Here's how we call the block from a method:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
  if block_given?
    yield( name )
  end
end

say_hi("Mridang") do |str|
  puts "Your name has #{str.length} letters."
end
#=> Hi, Mridang!
#=> Your name has 7 letters.
```

We use `block_given?` to see whether or not a block was passed along or not. In this case we passed an argument back to the block; it's up to your method to decide what to pass to the block. For example:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
  yield( name, name.reverse ) if block_given?
end

say_hi("Mridang"){ |str1, str2| puts "Is your name #{str1} or #{str2}?" }
#=> Hi, Mridang!
#=> Is your name Mridang or gnadirM?
```

It's just a convention (and a good one, and one you want to support) for some classes to pass the instance just created to the block.

Hopefully this helps you understand @SimoneCarletti's answer better, and will help you use blocks throughout your future programming.