# Best explanation of Ruby blocks?

Tags: ruby, block

What is the best explanation for Ruby blocks that you can share?

Both usage and writing code that can take a block?

Comment: Are you looking for an introduction to the concept of blocks, or an exhaustive reference on them?

Comment: Or are you just trolling for rep by asking questions that you don't need the answers to, don't intend to accept, and don't intend to even participate in the discussion of? We'll see if you reply.

Comment: This is a useful thread: http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 38):

I offer up my own explanation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885326/writing-a-method-that-takes-parameters-on-different-lines-in-ruby/4889989#4889989), slightly modified:

"Blocks" in Ruby are not the same as the general programming terms "code block" or "block of code".

Pretend for a moment that the following (invalid) Ruby code actually worked:

```
def add10( n )
  puts "#{n} + 10 = #{n+10}"
end

def do_something_with_digits( method )
  1.upto(9) do |i|
    method(i)
  end
end

do_something_with_digits( add10 )
#=> "1 + 10 = 11"
#=> "2 + 10 = 12"
...
#=> "9 + 10 = 19"
```

While that code is invalid, its intent—passing some code to a method and having that method run the code—is possible in Ruby in a variety of ways. One of those ways is "Blocks".

A Block in Ruby is very, very much like a method: it can take some arguments and run code for those. Whenever you see `foo{ |x,y,z| ... }` or `foo do |x,y,z| ... end`, those are blocks that take three parameters and run the `...` on them. *(You might even see that the `upto` method above is being passed a block.)*

Because Blocks are a special part of the Ruby syntax, every method is allowed to be passed a block. Whether or not the method *uses* the block is up to the method. For example:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
end

say_hi("Mom") do
  puts "YOU SUCK!"
end
#=> Hi, Mom!
```

The method above is passed a block that is ready to issue an insult, but since the method never calls the block, only the nice message is printed. Here's how we call the block from a method:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
  if block_given?
    yield( name )
  end
end

say_hi("Mridang") do |str|
  puts "Your name has #{str.length} letters."
end
#=> Hi, Mridang!
#=> Your name has 7 letters.
```

We use `block_given?` to see whether or not a block was passed along or not. In this case we passed an argument back to the block; it's up to your method to decide what to pass to the block. For example:

```
def say_hi( name )
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
  yield( name, name.reverse ) if block_given?
end

say_hi("Mridang"){ |str1, str2| puts "Is your name #{str1} or #{str2}?" }
#=> Hi, Mridang!
#=> Is your name Mridang or gnadirM?
```

It's just a convention (and a good one, and one you want to support) for some classes to pass the instance just created to the block.

*This is not an exhaustive answer, as it does not cover capturing blocks as arguments, how they handle arity, un-splatting in block parameters, etc. but intends to serve as a Blocks-Are-Lambdas intro.*

Comment: Surprised to see, there are only 29(including mine) upvotes for the answer in more than 7 years. The concept can be known. But the way you explain, "KUDOS!". Definitely recommended for beginners.

Answer (score 27):

Ruby blocks are a way of creating [`Proc` objects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) which represent code that can be used by other code.  Proc objects are instructions between curly braces `{}` (or `do...end` phrases for multiline blocks, which have lower precedence than curly braces) which may optionally take arguments and return values (e.g. `{|x,y| x+y}`).  Procs are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object) and can be constructed explicitly or attained implicitly as method pseudo-arguments:

1. Construction as a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) object (or using the `lambda` keyword):

   ```
   add1 = Proc.new {|x| x+1} # Returns its argument plus one.
   add1.call(1) # => 2
   ```
2. Passed as a method pseudo argument, either explicitly using the special `&` last-argument syntax sugar operator or implicitly using a `block_given?`/`yield` pair:

   ```
   def twice_do(&proc) # "proc" is the block given to a call of this method.
     2.times { proc.call() } if proc
   end
   twice_do { puts "OK" } # Prints "OK" twice on separate lines.

   def thrice_do() # if a block is given it can be called with "yield".
     3.times { yield } if block_given?
   end
   thrice_do { puts "OK" } # Prints "OK" thrice on separate lines.
   ```

The second form is typically used for [Visitor patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern); data can be passed to the special block arguments as arguments to the `call` or `yield` methods.

Comment: Braces have a high precedence; `do` has a low precedence. If the method invocation has parameters that are not enclosed in parentheses, the brace form of a block will bind to the last parameter, not to the overall invocation. The `do` form will bind to the invocation.

Comment: English, please! ......"Ruby blocks are syntax literals for Proc objects...." - if people don't know what a block is, I am guessing they won't know what  "syntax literals for Proc objects" means either. try to explain as if readers were 5 years old.

Comment: What is a syntax literal?

Comment: @DerrickMar: by "syntax literal" i meant essentially "the arrangement of language tokens in their most basic sense".  For example, in JavaScript, the sequence of characters `/\d+/` is a syntax literal meaning "a regular expression matching one or more digits".  Similarly, blocks are a direct way of defining procedures in Ruby which can be passed around as first-class objects (arguments-to and return-values-from other methods and procedures in Ruby).

Answer (score 20):

From [Why's (poignant) guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-3.html):

> Any code surrounded by curly braces is
>   a block.
>
> `2.times { print "Yes, I've used
>   chunky bacon in my examples, but never
>   again!" }` is an example.
>
> With blocks, you can group a set of
>   instructions together so that they can
>   be passed around your program. The
>   curly braces give the appearance of
>   crab pincers that have snatched the
>   code and are holding it together. When
>   you see these two pincers, remember
>   that the code inside has been pressed
>   into a single unit. It’s like one of
>   those little Hello Kitty boxes they
>   sell at the mall that’s stuffed with
>   tiny pencils and microscopic paper,
>   all crammed into a glittery
>   transparent case that can be concealed
>   in your palm for covert stationary
>   operations. Except that blocks don’t
>   require so much squinting. The curly
>   braces can also be traded for the
>   words do and end, which is nice if
>   your block is longer than one line.

```
loop do
  print "Much better."    
  print "Ah. More space!"
  print "My back was killin' me in those crab pincers."
end
```

> Block arguments are a
>   set of variables surrounded by pipe
>   characters and separated by commas.

```
|x|, |x,y|, and |up, down, all_around| are examples.
```

> Block arguments are used
>   at the beginning of a block.

```
{ |x,y| x + y }
```

> In the above example, |x,y| are the arguments. After the arguments, we
>   have a bit of code. The expression x +
>   y adds the two arguments together. I
>   like to think of the pipe characters
>   as representing a tunnel. They give
>   the appearance of a chute that the
>   variables are sliding down. (An x goes
>   down spread eagle, while the y neatly
>   crosses her legs.) This chute acts as
>   a passageway between blocks and the
>   world around them. Variables are
>   passed through this chute (or tunnel)
>   into the block.

Comment: "Any code surrounded by curly braces is a block" unless it is a **hash**.

Comment: You don't explain what these examples return. I don't get it.

Comment: Please be my tutor! Thank you for explaining it in such a straightforward and clear way.

Answer (score 7):

For anybody coming to this question from a C# background (or other langs really), this might help:

Ruby blocks are like lambda expressions and anonymous methods in C#. They are what C# calls delegates (and Ruby calls Procs), which is to say that they are essentially functions that can be passed as values. In both Ruby and C#, they can also behave as closures.

Ruby: `{ |x| x + 1 }`

C#: `x => x + 1`

Ruby: `{ |name| puts "Hello there #{name}" }`

C#: `name => { Console.WriteLine("Hello there {0}", name); }`

Both C# and Ruby offer alternative ways to write the above example.

Ruby:

```
do |name|
   puts "Hello there #{name}"
end
```

C#:

```
delegate(string name)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello there {0}", name);
}
```

In both Ruby and C#, multiple statements are allowed, In Ruby, the second syntax above is required for this.

These concepts are available in many other languages that have been influenced by the ideas behind functional programming.

Answer (score 6):

The book "[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)" has a great [explanation of blocks and using them](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html#S2).

In 1.9+, the parameter list passed into a block became more sophisticated, allowing local variables to be defined:

```
do |a,b;c,d| 
  some_stuff
end
```

`;c,d` declare two new local variables inside the block, that do not receive values from the called-routine's `yield` statement. Ruby 1.9+ guarantees that, if the variables existed outside the block, that they will not be stomped on by the same-named variables inside the block. This is new behavior; 1.8 would stomp on them.

```
def blah
  yield 1,2,3,4
end

c = 'foo'
d = 'bar'

blah { |a, *b; c,d|
  c = 'hello'
  d = 'world'
  puts "a: #{a}", "b: #{b.join(',')}", "c: #{c}", "d: #{d}" 
}

puts c, d
# >> a: 1
# >> b: 2,3,4
# >> c: hello
# >> d: world
# >> foo
# >> bar
```

There's also the "splat" operator `*`, which works in the list of parameters:

```
do |a,*b| 
  some_stuff
end
```

Would assign the first of multiple values to "a", and all the rest would be captured in "b" which would be treated like an array. The `*` could be on the `a` variable:

```
do |*a,b| 
  some_stuff
end
```

would capture all passed in variables except the last one, which would be passed to `b`. And, similarly to the two previous:

```
do |a,*b,c| 
  some_stuff
end
```

would assign the first value to `a`, the last value to `c` and all/any intervening values to `b`.

I think that's pretty powerful and slick.

For instance:

```
def blah
  yield 1,2,3,4
end

blah { |a, *b| puts "a: #{a}", "b: #{b.join(',')}" }
# >> a: 1
# >> b: 2,3,4

blah { |*a, b| puts "a: #{a.join(',')}", "b: #{b}" }
# >> a: 1,2,3
# >> b: 4

blah { |a, *b, c| puts "a: #{a}", "b: #{b.join(',')}", "c: #{c}" }
# >> a: 1
# >> b: 2,3
# >> c: 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Blocks are lightweight literals for anonymous first-class procedures with some annoying limitations. They work the same way in Ruby as they work in pretty much every other programming language, modulo the afore-mentioned limitations, which are:

- blocks can only appear in argument lists
- at most one block can appear in an argument list (and it must be the last argument)

Comment: Good answer but the relationship to Proc objects seems essential, no?

Comment: @maerics Essential to an exhaustive resource on Blocks? Yes. Essential to an explanation of blocks (which I interpret as being an introduction to them for the novice)? Definitely not, IMO.

Comment: Thanks. Yours is the only answer that helped me understand why `{puts "hello"}` does not work. Not allowed at all? That's weird.

Answer (score 3):

Blocks are a way of grouping code in Ruby.  There are two ways to write blocks. One is using the do..end statement and the other is surrounding the code in curly braces: {}.  Blocks are considered objects in the Ruby programming language, and by default all functions accept an implicit block argument.

Here are two examples of blocks that do the same thing:

```
2.times { puts 'hi' }
2.times do
  puts 'hi'
end
```

Blocks can receive lists of comma-separated arguments inside vertical bars ||. For example:

```
[1,2].map{ |n| n+2 } # [3, 4]
```

Blocks (in ruby 1.9.2) can explicitly have local variables:

```
x = 'hello'
2.times do |;x|
  x = 'world'
  puts x
end

=> world
=> world
```

Local variables can be combined with parameters:

```
[1,2].map{ |n;x| n+2 }
```

All functions can receive a default block argument:

```
def twice
  yield
  yield
end

twice { puts 'hello' }
=> hello
=> hello
```

What is the difference between do..end and {} blocks? By convention {} blocks are on a single line and do..end blocks span multiple lines, since they are each easier to read this way.  The main difference has to do with precedence though:

```
array = [1,2]

puts array.map{ |n| n*10 } # puts (array.map{ |n| n*10 })
=> 10
=> 20

puts array.map do |n| n*10 end # (puts array.map) do |n| n*10 end
=> <Enumerator:0x00000100862670>
```