# Instantiating instance variable as block

Tags: ruby

I have the following class

```
class Increasable

  def initializer(start, &increaser)
    @value = start
    @increaser = increaser
  end

  def increase()
    value = increaser.call(value)
  end
end
```

How do I initialize with a block? Doing

```
inc = Increasable.new(1, { |val|  2 + val})
```

in `irb` I get

```
(irb):20: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
inc = Increasable.new(1, { |val|  2 + val})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method calling syntax was incorrect.

```
class Increasable
  attr_reader :value, :increaser

  def initialize(start, &increaser)
    @value = start
    @increaser = increaser
  end

  def increase
    @value = increaser.call(value)
  end
end

Increasable.new(1) { |val|  2 + val }.increase # => 3
```

Read [Best explanation of Ruby blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911353/best-explanation-of-ruby-blocks) to know how blocks work in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I see different mistakes in your code. After correcting, you can apply **lambdas**.

```
class Increasable
  def initialize(start, increaser)
    @value = start
    @increaser = increaser
  end

  def increase()
    @value = @increaser.call(@value)
  end
end
```

And call it by:

```
inc = Increasable.new(1, ->(val){ 2 + val}) # => 3
```

Some links that can help to understand what happens:

1. [Lambdas](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/34-lambdas-and-blocks-in-ruby/lessons/77-lambdas-in-ruby)
2. [Classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm)
3. [Lambdas 2](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/64-blocks-procs-lambdas)