# Some simple questions about Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following simple code in a migration file in Ruby on Rails :

```
def change
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.string :title 
end
```

Can I understand it like that :

1:  `create_table` is a ruby built-in ( or Ruby on Rails ? ) to create a table

2: `:articles` is the table name, so clear

3: This is the most important for me to illustrate in my brain. `do |t|` means to execute what is behind it ? this is mean `do` will add the table in the database, and gives it the value `t` ???

Comment: This is nothing like unix pipes, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: Hello, I know it is a simple question, but it is still hard for me to understand the role of pipe. I don't care about the rating of my profile on stackoverflow, I care about my knowledge; What is mean inside a Ruby on Rails code, with we use pipes, this is what I was asking for. Thanks for your negative reaction.

Comment: @Sergio, NO, I'm just asking about the role of pipes inside Ruby code. Thanks for your comment

Comment: If you truly do care about your knowledge, you shouldn't be getting piecemeal knowledge of very basic ruby syntax constructs from stackoverflow questions. You should be reading a book.

Comment: you are right Sergio, I'm following now video learning ( a course for the beginner) about 260 videos. I thought I can come to here for any question. Anyway, not easy to understand all things in one time.

Comment: Among those 260 videos, there must be several about blocks. Find those and watch. Should clear the concept for you.

Comment: I'm at 20% now of the course, but so happy. Anyway he explained quickly about the do, and I'm still learning. I will not post here any future simple question, do you know a good community to help me understand these small issues ? Thanks again for your help Sergio!

Answer (score 1):

What you see here is a block, one of ruby's most powerful language constructs. `create_table` is called with the first parameter being a symbol indicating the name of the table, and the second parameter being a block (the bits between `do` and `end`). Assuming this is Rails, you can read more about that method [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table). The pipes indicate that `t` is a block parameter, which in this case refers to the table being created.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912143/3160670) goes into more depth about what blocks are.

Comment: Thank you Munyari, interesting and I'm following the link now.